# ProfileUpdateView: Generic detail view ProfileUpdateView must be called with either an object pk or a slug in the URLconf

Tags: django-views, django-class-based-views

I tried to make a cbv class to generate a profile update function. I use username in URL, but there is always a mistake

AttributeError at /edit_profile/apani
Generic detail view ProfileUpdateView must be called with either an object pk or a slug in the URLconf

I don't want to use pk to generate the URL.

```
#urls.py

urlpatterns = [
 path(
        'edit_profile/<slug:name>',
        views.ProfileUpdateView.as_view(),
        name='edit_profile'
    ),
path('profile/<str:name>/', views.profile_info, name='profile')
]

#views.py

class ProfileUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = User
    form_class = ProfileForm
    template = 'blog/user.html'

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user_item = get_object_or_404(User, username=kwargs['name'])
        if self.user_item.username != self.request.user.get_username():
            return redirect('login')
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_success_url(self):
        username = self.kwargs['name']
        return reverse('blog:profile', kwargs={'name': username})


def profile_info(request, name):
    templates = 'blog/profile.html'
    user = get_object_or_404(
        User,
        username=name,
    )
    profile_post = user.posts.all().order_by('-pub_date')
    paginator = Paginator(
        profile_post,
        constants.PAGINATOR_PROFILE_POSTS_COUNT
    )
    page_number = request.GET.get('page')
    page_obj = paginator.get_page(page_number)
    context = {
        'profile': user,
        'page_obj': page_obj,
    }
    return render(request, templates, context)

#forms.py

class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            'username',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'email'
        )
```

I added slug_url_kwarg = 'name' but there is a field error, because built-in model User has no slug field

Answer (score 0):

> I added slug_url_kwarg = 'name' but there is a field error, because built-in model User has no slug field

That is not correct. The field error occurs because there is no field called 'name' in the default implementation of a `User`. The field is called 'username'.

But you are right. The username is more or less a string, not a slug. I would therefore recommend going with `str` within your urls.py instead of `slug`.

```py
urlpatterns = [
 path(
        'edit_profile/<str:name>/',
        views.ProfileUpdateView.as_view(),
        name='edit_profile'
    ),
]
```

Just leave the view and the form as it is in your question.

The problem is most likely to be found when you enter or build the url. Right now you are probably trying to build the url roughly like this

```
url = domain + 'edit_profile/' + user.name
```

Here it has to be `user.username`.

In the end this should work

```py
u = User.objects.create(username='Bob', ...)
```

And then access `www.your-domain.com/edit_profile/bob/`.

Comment: I changed urls to str like this, but the problem still the same - Generic detail view needs pk or slug 
` path( 'edit_profile/<str:name>', views.ProfileUpdateView.as_view(), name='edit_profile' ),`

url builds correctly

` def get_success_url(self):
        username = self.kwargs['name']
        return reverse('blog:profile', kwargs={'name': username})`

Comment: `return reverse('blog:profile', kwargs={'name': username})` does not build the url for the UpdateView. It builds the url for the DetailView which you did not show. So please show how you are building the url for the `ProfileUpdateView` with the name `'edit_profile'`

Comment: `path(
        'edit_profile/<str:name>',
        views.ProfileUpdateView.as_view(),
        name='edit_profile'
    ),`

Comment: I should explicitly specify the url inside the view function?

Comment: You just repeated what you already wrote 2 times. I want to see that piece of code that sends the user to your `blog:edit_profile` or at least what is the url you are entering when you try to access the `ProfileUpdateView`?

Comment: Ok, I think I know what is happening. I feel like the code you displayed (UPDATEview) is running just fine. Then it enters the block with the `get_success_url` and then it fails when trying to access the DETAILview. But the problem is you did not show the url of the detail view and neither the code of the detailview. Maybe you could add that via the edit function to your question

Comment: The problem is that I use view function to display profile page, not cbv)
I added that piece of code in my question, but I'm going to rewrite it to DETAILview soon.

Maybe I should make new model on the base of User, which will have the slug field?

Comment: The problem was solved by adding 
def get_object(self):
        self.user = get_object_or_404(User, username=self.kwargs['name'])
        return self.user
to UpdateView